# Forming proper structure inside AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, structure

Lets say I have 10 models (tables) inside my DB and I want to build an AngularJS application based on that DB. My question here is what is the best practice when forming AngularJS structure of application?

Should I declare 1 module within the application and use that module for all of my services and controllers?

When I have a following scenario: student model and teacher model ... Should I create separate controller.js file for student and teacher, and should I create separate service.js files for student and teacher?? Or all services can be held in one JS file? Can someone clear this up for  me please? I'd really like to hear this from people who have somewhat "live" experience working with AngularJS applications?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: grouping by feature not by component type is far more scaleable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just my opinion, but it's worked well for me.

You can have one service per backend controller, at least that's how I like to map it. For example, if you have a bunch of restful endpoints to manipulate the teachers table, you could have a `Teacher` service in Angular that can perform these restful actions. You can then also have a separate `Student` service that can perform restful actions on your database's students.

As for controllers, it depends. If you use routes, your best bet is to go with one controller per route. In any case, your controllers are more like a container for a view, they don't represent data. Having said that, if you're going to structure your Angular app around data, you could have something like this (at least this is how I like to structure my Angular apps):

```
-- app.js
-- /services
  -- teacher.js
  -- student.js
-- /controllers
  -- /teachers
    -- listTeachersController.js
    -- showTeacherController.js
    -- editTeacherController.js
  -- /students
    -- listStudentsController.js
    -- showStudentController.js
    -- editStudentController.js
-- /views
  -- /teachers
    -- index.html
    -- show.html
    -- edit.html
  -- /students
    -- index.html
    -- show.html
    -- edit.html
-- /directives
  ...
-- /interceptors
  ...
-- /filters
```

In your routes, you can then hook up your listTeachersController with the template in views/teachers/index.html, the showTeacherController with views/teachers/show.html, etc. Same for students.

But it really depends. Your front end may not follow a strict restful style, and maybe it shouldn't. I like to have one controller page, but as the page gets more complex, it may be time to break it up into sub-controllers that inherit from the page's controller.

Lastly, as for modules, I would just go with one module for the entire app, unless your app is huge. It keeps things simple.

Take this with a grain of salt. This is just my opinion and may or may not work well for you depending on what you're trying to build.

Comment: when it comes down to *"just my opinion"* you should know by now with your rep that question is off topic and should be doing the proper thing and voting to close for that reason

Comment: Thanks a lot for the excellent answer! This is the exact info that I needed! :)

Comment: @perkes456 Highfive!

Comment: Btw how many years of experience do you have with Angular? :) I've started to familiarize myself with Angular like 6-7 days ago, and I have to say that I'm amazed with what I've seen so far. P.S. Do you have some useful links where I could expand my knowledge on Angular? :)

Comment: I've been doing it for some 1.5 years now. This guide helped me quite a bit starting off: https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator to help you organize your application. There are many so you may have to try a few until you find one that you like. I like this one: https://github.com/Iteam1337/generator-mrwhite

Comment: Good call. The [yo generator for Angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) has also worked well for me.